# iOS development computer crashed - Is my application going to be able to receive updates?

Tags: ios

So my harddrive crashed on my development laptop. I am using a new mac now, but how do I get to developing again? I have my project on github, so my code is safe but, my one app is on the appstore and it needs an update. Am I fine when it comes to releasing an update or am I screwed because I don't have the key to sign the app? Also, is there any documentation on what to do with the provisioning profiles and such? It was extremely hard for me to set it up the first time, and the entire concept of provisioning profiles/development profiles/distribution profiles still confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

You are fine.

If you have the source you can release an update to your app, by checking out your git repo, building it with the same bundle id and submitting to the app store.

I agree the provisioning / App ID / cert process is convoluted. However, good for you, you can replace any signing certs/keys/profiles. All that's required to update an existing app is the source and the same bundle ID.

Regarding tutorials on the subject out [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2915/ios-code-signing-under-the-hood).

Comment: You have just saved me a from a mini heart attack. Thanks for the reasurance. Can you walk me through the steps for getting my certificates? Is there any way that my bundle ID could be deleted?'

Comment: Nope, your bundle ID is associated with your currently released app and visible when you 'manage' your apps on iTunes Connect, sure I can walk you through the steps, have a go and let me know when you get stuck. Step 1: go to developer.apple.com

Comment: are you using a new mac?

Comment: Yes. It has xcode, and I have my code pulled in from github, but I haven't done anything dealing with ios Dev center/certificates/identifiers/profiles.

Comment: If you don't have your certificates backed up, you'll be revoking them and generating new ones. That's perfectly fine. Xcode will probably even walk you through it.

Comment: Nope. I don't have anything backed up except for me code. Unless, that somehow gets saved on git. In android my signing key gets backed up using git. Im unsure/confused how ios handles it.

Comment: okay first you need to revoke your original certs and then create new ones (because you need to since you have a new computer with new private keys)

Comment: Okay, in certificates I have a development and distribution certificate. Should I revoke them both?

Comment: yup, create new ones and download

Comment: Okay, I am going to create a new development certificate. It needs me to make a CSR. Do I need this?

Comment: Should I have it emailed to the "CA" (dont know what that is) or saved to disc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51984/discussion-between-eghdk-and-john-woods)

Comment: I have the development CSR created. Do I need to create a new csr for my deployment certificate?